# Различие сравнения с типизированной и нетипизированной константой

Tags: компилятор, c++

С++ - веселая фишка (помогите разъяснить человеку). Значицо так, есть у меня товарищ - второй день ему объясняю непонятную ему проблему (до сих пор). Например, есть сравнение:

```
if (123123123 == num) // num - int
```

так вот. Человек не понимает разницы между выше показанным примером и следующим:

```
if ((int)123123123 == num)
```

Так вот, как объяснял я: 123123123 - компилятор не знает, что это такое (это все равно, что 1 может трактоваться как true, а 0 как false). Я ему рассказал, что 123123123 - это просто нетипизированный мусор, который компилятор произвольно приведет к типу, который ему понравится и исходя из этого мы можем получить аналогичное сравнение

```
if(true == num) //
```

И получается, что при любом num отличным от нуля условие будет верно.

Народ, если у кого-нибудь есть более понятное объяснение происходящего - напишите :) Ну оооочень нужно :)

Comment: Вы уверенны, кто кому правильно объясняет?
Компилятор прекрасно знает, что такое 123123123 - это число.
Да, и этот "специфичный стиль" константа впереди... Современные компиляторы очень хорошо ловят if(a=0) и ругаются. А присваивание там редко нужно.

Comment: Однако if (123123123 == num) и if (num == 123123123) сравнило по разному :) Ну ка, эксперты, Ваше мнение ? :D

Comment: Что значит "сравнило по разному" ? Последовательность машинных команд другая ? Какой тип у num ?

Тест на "по разному" в студию.

Comment: Какой компилятор? битность? и правильно ли код написан? А то может там такое

    if (m == 123123123); {
      std::cout << "nonono" << std::endl;
    }

Comment: KoVadim - нет. Я явно написал строку и никаких ";" там нет.
Компилятор - G++, 64, все под Debian. Работая среда - codelite

Comment: Ну правильный ответ остаётся тем же -- ПСНЛ (подземный стук не лечим). Пример -- в студию!

Comment: Станислав, не знаю, что Вы там написали, я написал аналогичный пример, и у меня разницы не было никакой.

Comment: @mikillskegg Было бы в высшей мере удивительно, если бы результат был иным.

Comment: Да кто его знает, всякое бывает, может я что-то не понимаю. Оказывается, понимаю )))

Answer (score 4):

Неименованные целочисленные константы приводятся либо к int, либо (если их значение превышается лимиты int) к long. Тоже с плавающей запятой - float - double. Чтобы явно указать, что хотим получить long или double, в конце пишем L: 44L, 464.22L.

Есть такое понятие - неявное приведение типов. Это когда в одном выражении (арифметическая операция, сравнение и т.д.) встречаются переменные или константы нескольких типов. Приведение осуществляется к самому "длинному" типу. В Вашем случае разницы между двумя выражениями по сути нет, Ваш друг прав.

В случае с bool, надо помнить, что bool по сути является типом char (в отличии от Джавы, где этот вид к целочисленному просто так не приводиться) и при неявном приведении будет приводиться просто к 0 или 1. Остальные виды будут приводиться к bool только при явном приведении.

Answer (score 3):

Не обманывайте человека. Целочисленый литерал без суфикса может быть преобразован только int, long int или long long int, в зависимости от размера, но никак не к bool.
Но в принципе вы правы, у меня (64-битная архитектура) следующий пример выводит только "First":

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int i = 2147483647;
    if ((int)66571993087 == i) {
        std::cout << "First" << std::endl;
    }
    if (66571993087 == i) {
        std::cout << "Second" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Это происходит из-за того, что 66571993087 не помещается в int, поэтому имеет тип long long int.
В первом сравнении мы приводим его к int, поэтому теряем старшие разряды и получаем 2147483647. Во втором сравнении i приводится к типу long long.